# Multiple SQL Standard Instances on 4 Processor/32-core Server

Tags: derived-instances

We have a large 4 processor/32-core server with 192GB of memory available in the data center and over twenty small SQL Standard databases to consolidate.   They are a mix of SQL 2012 and 2008 R2 for 3rd-party apps.

Is there any issue with simply installing two instances of SQL Standard on the server - one for 2012 and one for 2008 R2 ?  Each instance will use up to 64GB out of the 192GB and 16 cores.  If we did this with Enterprise, the licensing would be a fortune and the Enterprise features are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure you need to install the two versions. You could put 2012 on and set the compatibility level for the 2008 databases accordingly. The manual states its not a total backwards compatibility with prior versions but running two entire servers on one box is going to cause issues even if it is only service patch conflict and contention for disk access.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx - what Microsoft advises